# How to make bevel and Embosed effect to button in CSS 3 for web-kit based browsers?

Tags: css, mobile-webkit

How to make bevel and Embosed effect to **Submit** button in CSS 3 ?

Like this.

[image]

Enlarged Image[image]

I'm only considering **Web-kit** based browsers. and **I'm not asking about How to give round corner and how to give gradient to button, I'm only asking about bevel effect**

**Html**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit your entry" class="input" />
```

Comment: Probably not possible without an additional surrounding element - but I can be wrong. Interested to see what comes up.

Comment: @pekka - if you know how to make this possible with an surrounding element, tell me.

Comment: It *should* be possible with a surrounding element with `box-shadow: inset ......`, creating the outer shadow, and an inner element with the gradient etc., and a normal `box-shadow`. It's fairly complex to do though, will require a lot of fiddling until it looks good.

Comment: @Pekka - please try here http://jsfiddle.net/vGHXg/1/

Comment: here's a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/vGHXg/19/

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This is possible without the use of extra mark-up through the use of multiple box-shadows:

```css
box-shadow: 
  0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
  0 -1px 1px #666, /*top external shadow*/ 
  inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/ 
  inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /*top internal highlight*/
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/NPXfe/

Comment: sexy button, but your comments are incorrect. "top internal highlight" and "bottom internal shadow" are backwards. an explanation of the 3 values would also be helpful..I'm trying to figure out what the 0 is in place of.

Comment: Fixed, the 0 is the x position of the shadow (relative to the element). http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: @Martin in that case you can always add a parent element and apply the inset box shadows to it.

Comment: Of course, but those looking for a semantic html friendly way to do this might not realize that at first. Also, your answer implies that all is needed is this box shadow.

Comment: @Martin so your solution is...? You could hack your way out with pseudo-elements but that's too much of a compromise for semantic code.

Comment: My solution would be exactly as you described *in your comments*. I'm just saying you might want to be more clear in your answer body, for those who are skimming through. They might believe they can accomplish what is desired with just a `box-shadow`, since that's what you answer suggests.