# Can I make this silver gradient effect login form using css3?

Tags: forms, css, authentication

I am trying to create this [Login form PSD](http://www.psdbird.com/metalic-login-form-psd/) using css3.

I have reached following (Gradiant) code but it not working. Can I achieve this design using css3? .

```
background: #e2e2e2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%, #fefefe 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e2e2e2 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#d1d1d1 51%,#fefefe 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e2e2e2 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#d1d1d1 51%,#fefefe 100%);
```

Thanks for your value help ..

Regards, Kevin

Comment: This might help you... http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ thought it doesn´t work on IE < 9 i guess

Comment: wow.. thank you shoaib. It is working well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gradients [Link 1](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) and [Link 2](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)

For bevel emboss effect on button and input : [How to make bevel and Embosed effect to button in CSS 3 for web-kit based browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754439/how-to-make-bevel-and-embosed-effect-to-button-in-css-3-for-web-kit-based-browse)

[For bevel emboss effect on text](http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-7-great-css-based-text-effects-using-the-text-shadow-property_2011-03-03.html)

[For checkbox styling](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one it might work!!

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 left top,
 left bottom,
 color-stop(0.48, #204D8B),
 color-stop(0.74, #3E71B5)
 );
```

Comment: but I need a vertical gradient form . How it possible? do you know vertical code?

Comment: Try this! background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.48, #8B206D), color-stop(0.74, #3EA2B5) );