# Using only straight html and css how do I make backgound web page colours, and also images, appear to have a shiny/glossy look to them?

Tags: html, css

Using only straight html and css how do I make background web page colours, and also images, appear to have a shiny/glossy look to them?

I am **not** talking about making a gradient going between two different colours **but rather** adding a glossy (or shiny) appearance to standard hex colours and to images.

Something like the glossy effect that coats of clear have on paint jobs on vehicles.

Some sort of glossy/shiny overlay?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); we can't resolve your problem without seeing it! ;) It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I don't have a problem - what I have works - it is just standard html/css

body {
 background-color:#025e8c;
 font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
}

I just want the page to look like a glossy magazine not a dull looking hex background colour. Beyond my question and this explaination I don't know how else to communicate my wishes?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754439/how-to-make-bevel-and-embosed-effect-to-button-in-css-3-for-web-kit-based-browse
The effect you're after is perhaps "bevel and emboss"?

Answer (score -1):

Your going to want to use CSS do add to your colors. If you want to use glossy colors you should use a color picker that gives you multiple suggestions. https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp

Comment: I already have hex colours picked, and the CSS is doing the colours.

I was hoping for something like the glossy effect that coats of clear have on paint jobs on vehicles.

Some sort of glossy/shiny overlay?

Obviously not possible?

Comment: Your best bet is either finding what colors you want and taking them to Photoshop and designing your page using or other adobe products such as illustrated. Besides that there's no special code that makes it glossy that I can think of threw the languages I know.

Answer (score -1):

You could add multiple different shadows using [**`box-shadow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to the desired elements:

```css
div {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #025e8c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px gold, 0 0 150px red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: It could be. I will try using box-shadow and see what the result looks like. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of is something like:

```
filter: saturate(200%);
```

or

```
filter: contrast(200%);
```

or... perhaps both (?)

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
float: left;
}

div, div h2 {
margin: 6px;
}

.contrast img {
filter: contrast(300%);
}

.saturate img {
filter: saturate(600%);
}

.contrast img {
filter: contrast(300%);
}

.contrast-saturate img {
filter: saturate(600%) contrast(300%);
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Standard</h2>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/120/180" title="Normal Image" alt="Kitten" />
</div>

<div class="contrast">
<h2>Contrast</h2>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/120/180" title="Image with Contrast" alt="Contrasted Kitten" />
</div>

<div class="saturate">
<h2>Saturate</h2>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/120/180" title="Image with Saturation" alt="Saturated Kitten" />
</div>

<div class="contrast-saturate">
<h2>Both</h2>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/120/180" title="Image with Both" alt="Processed Kitten" />
</div>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter